# How to Terminate Read at EndOfFile

Tags: string-manipulation, streams

We are working on a project that reads in a stream, extracts information from it, and then needs to stop the calculation when it reaches `EndOfFile`.

So for example, this works to grab the first ten records (or ten from wherever the stream's current position is):

```
Do[
 tempRecord = Read[wFile, Record, RecordSeparators -> {"WARC/1.0" }];
 tempRecordAssociation = recordToAssociation[tempRecord];
 Print[tempRecordAssociation["WARC-Target-URI"]], 10]
```

But if it bumps up against the `EndOfFile`, we get the error:

> StringReplace::strse: "String or list of strings expected at
>   position..

Our ultimate goal is to get something like this working, where we can read the entire stream and it stops when it hits EndOfFile.

```
While[Reap[True, 
   tempRecord = 
    Read[wFile, Record, RecordSeparators -> {"WARC/1.0"}];
   tempRecordAssociation = recordToAssociation[tempRecord];
   Sow[tempRecordAssociation["WARC-Target-URI"]];
   If[StreamPosition[wFile] == EndOfFile, Break[]]]];
```

But, as a relative newcomer in working with streams, we can't figure out how to get the Read to stop on EndOfFile and store the results up until then. We tried `SameQ` to no avail.

So in short, **our question is: how can we get read to end when it hits EndOfFile?**

#### Appendix

In case the sample data and functions are useful, I will provide them below. I think this may be more of a conceptual question, however. Sample data file [can be found here as a Dropbox public download](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4619870/ARCHIVEIT-227-QUARTERLY-XUGECV-20091218231727-00039-crawling06.us.archive.org-8091.warc.txt). I will probably remove this data file later, but it is [this file](https://github.com/lintool/warcbase-resources/blob/master/Sample-Data/ARCHIVEIT-227-QUARTERLY-XUGECV-20091218231727-00039-crawling06.us.archive.org-8091.warc.gz) unzipped with a txt extension added manually.

File is loaded:

```
sampleWARCFile = 
  "/Users/ianmilligan1/dropbox/git/warcbase-resources/Sample-Data/\
ARCHIVEIT-227-QUARTERLY-XUGECV-20091218231727-00039-crawling06.us.\
archive.org-8091.warc.txt";
wFile = OpenRead[sampleWARCFile]
```

And the function is:

```
recordToAssociation[rec_] :=
 Module[{recmod, fields, vals},
  recmod = StringReplace[rec, "\r\n\r\n" -> "\r\n\r\nCONTENT: "];
  fields = 
   StringTrim[StringExtract[StringSplit[recmod, "\r"], ":" -> 1]];
  vals = Map[
    StringTrim[
      StringReplace[#, 
       Shortest[StartOfString ~~ Except[":"] ..] ~~ ":" -> ""]] &, 
    StringSplit[recmod, "\r"]];
  Return[Association[
    DeleteCases[MapThread[Rule, {fields, vals}], 
     Rule["", ""] | Rule["CONTENT", ""]]]]]
```

Comment: just test if `tmpRecord===EndOfFile` and control the logic appropriately.  aside if you are reading an entire file consider using `Import` instead

Comment: Thanks @george2079 – some of our files are too large to load into memory, so we're hoping to run them like so. Hopefully that's not a horrid idea.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your `While` condition and the positioning of `Reap` is a bit off.  Try the following

```
Reap[
 While[(tempRecord = Read[wFile, Record, RecordSeparators -> {"WARC/1.0"}]) =!= EndOfFile,
  tempRecordAssociation = recordToAssociation[tempRecord];
  Sow[tempRecordAssociation["WARC-Target-URI"]];
  ]
 ]
```

Hope this helps.